# Google Maps API v3 : Passing values to Listener function(), so as to make a circle when the marker is clicked?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I want to form a circle around the marker when the marker is clicked!

So, Listener is added to marker and the function needs to act on the circle.

Here is my Code :

```
   for(var j=0;j<lat.length;j++)
            {
                var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[j],lng[j]);
                var marker_options = {position: pos, map:map, draggable:false};
                marker[j] = new google.maps.Marker(marker_options);
                circle_option = {strokeColor:"#FF0000",strokeOpacity:0.8,strokeWeight:2,fillColor:"#FF0000",fillOpacity:0.35,map:null,center:pos,radius:500};
                circle[j] = new google.maps.Circle(circle_option);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker[j], 'click', function() {circle[j].setMap(map);});  // Error : circle[j] is undefined
            }
```

Error: circle[j] is undefined ?? (On the event.addListener line !)

Why.. it should be defined there ?

How to do this is the right way ? Please help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have a closure problem with `j`. When your function is called, `j` will reference the last value that `j` had in the for loop. So, `j` will be `lat.length` which is larger than the size of `circle`. The solution is to force `j` to be evaluated when generating the callback function:

```
function make_callback(circle, map) {
    return function() {
        circle.setMap(map);
    };
}
```

and then, in your loop:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker[j], 'click', make_callback(circle[j], map));
```

Wrapping the callback generation in a separate function will give you the value of `circle[j]` at the instant when you call `make_callback` rather than the value when the callback is called.

`j` is a reference to a value, the value that it points at depends on when you ask `j` what its value is. When you bind a function like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker[j], 'click', function() { something(j); });
```

The anonymous function doesn't ask `j` what its value is until the function is called, the function simply remembers that it is going to use `j`. When the callback function is executing, it will ask `j` for its current value and use that. This means two things:

- All the callbacks that you bound in that loop will use the same value of `j`.
- `j` will be `lat.length` as that's the last value that `j` was assigned during the loop.

By using the `make_callback` function to build the callbacks, we're asking `j` for its value at the time that we're binding the callback. This is just a standard trick to force `j` to be evaluated when it has the value we want.

Comment: Can you share some resources to study about closures in Javascript.. As I am not able to understand what you did ?

Comment: I did it in a flash because I (like all JavaScript developers) have made that mistake before. The MDN documentation tends to be good so maybe their page on closures will help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: @Yugal: I add some more notes that may help clarify things.

Comment: Again.. got stuck and this answer saved me again. I am still not getting why does the anonymous function is not taking the value on the run.. ?

Comment: @Yugal: By the time it gets called, `j` is `lat.length`. The closure just grabs the variable (which keeps varying as the loop runs), not the variable's value at that instant in time. The extra function call forces the variable to evaluated so that you get its current value rather than dragging around a pointer to something that changes behind your back.