# Custom mouse interaction for SVG layer in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, d3.js, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I'm in the process of building a D3 layer in Google maps. I'm at the stage where D3 renders fine, but mouse events that I want to affect this layer are caught by (I think) the overlayMouseTarget layer. This means I can't have any interaction with my D3 layer.

I've searched here and elsewhere for fixes, however after implementing several suggestions I found I am still left without a working solution. Are there any supported methods for either overloading mouse interactions or removing/hiding the mouse interaction layer in Google Maps? Or perhaps there is a more elegant solution?

I could do something like [Google Maps API v3 : Passing values to Listener function(), so as to make a circle when the marker is clicked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838868/google-maps-api-v3-passing-values-to-listner-function-so-as-to-make-a-circl) and have my D3 code completely divorced from any layer, but I'd rather have it in a layer sandwiched below the layer with the zoom/pan controller and above the mouse event layer. Or figure out how to send events down several layers to where my D3 code currently lives.

I used https://gist.github.com/899711 as a starting point for adding D3 into Maps.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same question, a fix that works for me was to bind the entire svg layer to `this.getPanes().overlayMouseTarget` instead of the original `this.getPanes().overlayLayer`.